# Existence of solutions to system of quadratic equations

Tags: quadratic-forms

I am currently trying to understand when the following system of equations has a solution:
$$x^t U_i^\dagger U_j x = c_{ij}$$
Where the $U_i$ are $n$ by $n$ unitary matrices, $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $c_{ij}$ is a $k$ by $k$ matrix and $i$, $j$ are indices that run from 1 to $k$.

In particular, I would like to know what are some nontrivial necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $c_{ij}$ so that a solution exists.
For example, a necessary condition would be $c_{ii}=1$.

I've looked at a lot of questions and answers on this site, but they all seem to relate to specific instances (such as real variables) while I'm looking for either a general answer, or an answer specific to the unitary case.
The only one that comes close is [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284368/do-almost-all-systems-of-quadratic-equations-have-solutions) answer, but it's very vague.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Potential simplifying assumptions/other constraints**

1. I am ok with assuming that the eigenvalues of the $U_{ij}$ are $\pm 1$
2. If it's necessary, I can assume that $c_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$
3. $x$ should have unit norm